# Create a selector of styles

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to create an xml selector of styles.

Basically i would do something like that:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
      style="@style/filter_btn"/>
  <item android:state_pressed="false"
      style="@style/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Selectors work only for drawables, not styles.

[Reference](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8941)

Comment: Damn . Thanks :)  Do you have some ideas about how to accomplish this task ?

Comment: I'm afraid the only option I've seen is to handle it in code.  And I've found it easier, in those situations, to handle all of the changes in code, rather than splitting what can be handled in xml (drawables) there, and just the rest in code.  If I can't do it all with a `selector`, I just make the changes in code.