# Button background as transparent

Tags: android

I have a button. When I press the button I have to make text as bold otherwise normal. So I wrote styles for bold & normal.

```
<style name="textbold" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
<item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
<style name="textregular" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
<item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

Now I have a button_states.xml as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
    style="@style/textbold" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"
    style="@style/textregular" />

<item style="@style/textregular" />
</selector>
```

In my layout for this button, I have to make the background as transparent too...How will I do it? My layout code is :

```
<Button android:id="@+id/Btn" android:background="@drawable/button_states" />
```

How will I include background as transparent in my style?

Comment: So many of these good answers could be accepted by now...

Comment: check out [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856661/how-to-make-button-transparent-in-my-app-yet-visible#answer-12856901)  to make transparent button with border

Comment: ' why don't you just use a TextView and call the action on onClick of it ?

Answer (score 401):

To make a background transparent, just do `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`.

However, your problem seems to be a bit deeper, as you're using selectors in a really weird way. The way you're using it seems wrong, although if it actually works, you should be putting the background image in the style as an `<item/>`.

Take a closer look at how styles are used in the Android source. While they don't change the text styling upon clicking buttons, there are a lot of good ideas on how to accomplish your goals there.

Comment: Take a look at my clarified answer. I misread your problem to start. The background gets set in the style.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear on the solution. Just setting @android:color/transparent doesn't support the on-touch styles that normal buttons have (and is equivalent to setting the background to @null).

Comment: @gatoatigrado: do you mean that you want a transparent area to be outlined in orange or shaded in some what? If so, you'll need to create custom 9-patch images for that.

Comment: @StevePomeroy, yes, the default button effect on Android 4.1 is for [on button press] the background to be a light blue, with an even lighter blue outline.

Comment: @gatoatigrado: ok. If you want that, then you can't use a transparent button. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish there.

Comment: In Android Studio BumbleBee only the answer by @MuhammadAamirAli seems to work

Answer (score 141):

Try new way to set background transparent

> ```
>     android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
> ```

Comment: This is what I would recommend using. This way, you get to keep the beautiful material design animations for your buttons =)

Comment: this is better answer

Comment: If someone wants a round behavior, use: `                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

Answer (score 38):

You may also use:
in your xml:

```
android:background="@null"
```

or in code:

```
buttonVariable.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: Upvote for giving alternatives, love to see all the options!

Answer (score 35):

use `#0000` (only four zeros otherwise it will be considered as `black`) this is the color code for transparent. You can use it directly but I recommend you to define a color in color.xml so you can enjoy re-usefullness of the code.

Comment: Luckily this has already been defined for us as `@android:color/transparent`

Answer (score 35):

Add this in your **Xml** - `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Button"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Answer (score 31):

I achieved this with in XML with

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 12):

I used

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

and

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); works fine for me

Answer (score 9):

Selectors work only for drawables, not styles. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3659818/5722608)

---

**First**, to make the button background transparent use the following attribute as this will not affect the material design animations:

```
style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
```

There are many ways to style your button. Check out [this tutorial](https://medium.com/android-bits/android-material-button-e7b92cb014e0).

**Second**, to make the text bold on pressed, use this java code:

```
btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            // When the user clicks the Button
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                btn.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                break;

            // When the user releases the Button
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                btn.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use attribute **android:background** in **Button** xml like below.

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Or we can use **style**

`style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` for transparent and shadow less background.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by setting the colors alpha channel.

The color scheme is like this #AARRGGBB there A stands for alpha channel(transparency), R stands for red, G for green and B for blue.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** 
Create a new resource file in drawable and copy paste

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke android:color="#fff" android:width="2dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="25dp"/>
    <padding android:right="15dp" android:top="15dp" android:bottom="15dp" android:left="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

save it as ButtonUI(let's say)

**Step 2:** Apply the UI to the button xml

```
<Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="join the crew"
  android:background="@drawable/ButtonUI"
  android:textColor="#fff"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say extend `Borderless` style.

```
<style name="Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

to apply a transparent background to a button, just set the backgroundTint property to #00FFFFFF

```
        android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
```

Answer (score -1):

Code:

```
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Xml:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it easily by adding below attribute in xml file. This code was tested plenty of time.

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Why add this answer? This solution is already in two other answers, including the one with the most votes.

Answer (score -3):

You apply the background color as `transparent(light gray)` when you click the button.

```
ButtonName.setOnClickListener()
```

In the above method you set the background color of the button.

Comment: Worrying that this was upvoted. Don't do this, please. The future maintainer will curse your name. Set a background with a selector, and have one color/drawable for pressed and one for not. Don't write code to change it in the listener - that is NOT how this is done.