# Make buttons work

Tags: android, android-button

How do I add a button on a background image in Android?

I already added the background now I want to add a button and make it work within the background. I have tried to add multiple buttons but then they all don't work, I'm not sure if its the layout or something else.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="back"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:background="@drawable/scan1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false" />
```

i edited the code, so the "scan1" drawable is showing red.

Comment: please take a look at. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954102/button-background-as-transparent

Comment: you giving it a background image, how you expect it to be transparent ?!!

Comment: Muhammed, i got this image that has places where the buttons on the app should go, i made this my background image. now i want to put the buttons on those places then make them transparent so they blend with the background, i don't know if you understand me.

Answer (score 0):

Transparent button

```
 android:background="@null"
```

or

```
 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [FancyButtons](https://github.com/medyo/Fancybuttons) library to create buttons with transparent background. Set `fb_defaultColor` param as follows:

```
fancy:fb_defaultColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Using this library, you won't lose ripple effects on button clicks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Add this to your button `xml`.. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You may also use: in your xml:

```
android:background="@null"
```

or in code:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```