# How can I set the color and size of the text? (I use the selector)

Tags: android, android-selector

my source selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"  android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected" android:state_activated="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

an example of how I set the style  - button_normal.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#F1F4F2" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dip" />

</shape>
```

**how in the  "shape" set the size and color of the text?
maybe there is another way to set the size and color for the selector?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way is just for the background of the button.

You should use another selector on the 
`android:textColor="@color/your_color_selector"` and put this file under the `res/color folder`

Here is an example:

your_color_selector.xml

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/blue"/>
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
<item android:color="@android:color/black"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a style, and that define the text size, color, and drawable (also much more).

You can do something like that:

Create a file named style.xml in the values folder:

```
<style name="button_style">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/your_selector</item>
</style>
```

And then go to your Button declaration and define the style of a button for example :

```
<Button
  style="@style/button_style"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Button"/>
```

Comment: As shown in this answer as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682051/android-how-to-make-button-text-bold-when-pressed-or-focussed